# IBM Watson Assistant: Remember previous intent?

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Is it possible that the chatbot responds for example to node 7 taking into account an intent that was written in node 3?

Imagine that in the second question of the chatbot you say that you are a boy and then there is a jump to because there are equal questions for both genders, but then there is different information depending on having chosen a sex.

I don't want to ask that again. Then I want you to remember that attempt to decide.

Answer (score 1):

With [IBM Watson Assistant the dialog nodes typically react to conditions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-nodes). The conditions are based on evaluating the current intent, entities or context variables. Context variables can hold a value or remember settings across the evaluation of multiple dialog steps (nodes).

In your case, you would gather information with questions and user answers, e.g. by [utilizing slots](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-slots). The chatbot would remember the gender, age group and more. The dialog nodes could switch to the specific question or reponse based on that context data or jump to a gender-specific subgroup of questions if needed.

I would recommend to look into some of the more complex samples (tutorials) and how the dialogs make use of context variables.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm trying to use slots correctly but I don't now what is the node where i have to put them. In the first question or in the last?

Comment: Whenever you have input or pieces of it that you want to remember, then you store it in a context variable. One way of doing it is through slots, but you can also use expressions.